# Custom marker break when too many markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When the maps displays a [few markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbvWf.png), everything is fine, but when displaying "[too many markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFsLg.png)", the custom icon breaks and I have no idea why. Anyone knows how to solve this or is able to point me in the right direction?

This is the code I use for the custom marker

```
const getSvg = () => {
    return `<svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 29 34">
        <path class="icon__background" fill="#ffc845" d="M14.5 32.7c.5-.5 1.1-1 1.6-1.5 1.6-1.6 3.2-3.2 4.6-4.9 1.7-2 3.1-3.9 4.3-5.7 1.5-2.5 2.4-4.7 2.4-6.5 0-7.1-5.8-12.9-12.9-12.9C7.4 1.1 1.6 6.9 1.6 14c0 1.8.8 4 2.4 6.5 1.1 1.8 2.6 3.7 4.3 5.7 1.5 1.7 3 3.4 4.6 4.9l1.6 1.6zm0-13.4c-2.9 0-5.3-2.4-5.3-5.3s2.4-5.3 5.3-5.3 5.3 2.4 5.3 5.3-2.4 5.3-5.3 5.3z"/>
        <path class="icon__border" fill="#fff" d="M14.5 33.8l-2.1-2.1c-1.6-1.5-3.1-3.3-4.6-4.9-2-2.4-3.4-4.2-4.4-5.8-1.7-2.7-2.5-5-2.5-7 0-3.7 1.4-7.1 4.1-9.7C7.6 1.7 11 .4 14.6.4c7.5 0 13.6 6.1 13.6 13.7 0 1.8-.8 4.1-2.5 6.9-1.4 2.1-2.8 3.9-4.4 5.8-1.4 1.7-3.1 3.4-4.6 4.9l-.8.8c-.3.2-.5.5-.8.7l-.6.6zm-.2-31.9c-3.2 0-6.1 1.2-8.4 3.4-2.3 2.4-3.5 5.4-3.5 8.7 0 1.7.8 3.8 2.3 6.1.9 1.6 2.3 3.3 4.2 5.6 1.5 1.6 3 3.4 4.5 4.8l1.1 1.1.3-.3c.3-.2.5-.5.8-.7 1.6-1.6 3.2-3.2 4.6-4.8 1.5-1.8 2.9-3.7 4.3-5.6 1.5-2.5 2.3-4.5 2.3-6.1 0-6.7-5.5-12.2-12.2-12.2h-.3zm.2 18.2c-3.3 0-6-2.7-6-6.1s2.7-6.1 6-6.1 6 2.7 6 6.1-2.7 6.1-6 6.1zm0-10.7C12 9.4 10 11.5 10 14s2.1 4.6 4.5 4.6c2.5 0 4.5-2.1 4.5-4.6s-2-4.6-4.5-4.6z"/>
        </svg>`;
};
const svgUrl = 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(getSvg());
```

Comment: Ideally, when handling large amount of markers, we use [Marker Clusters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering) as loading multiple markers may cause latency issues and may reduce performance, you may try this if this will suit with your use case, this can also help to make your map look as neat as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing from an svg to a png solved the issue.